# Can I make an Android game in ActionScript3 + Flash?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, flash

**Question 1:** Is it possible to make an Android game using ActionScript3 and flash even if flashplayer won't be supported anymore in Android Devices?

**Question 2:** Is the only way to make 2D mobile offline games through Java(or device's native) language?

My desire is to start creating simple 2D games/apps with a cute graphic UI (something like "Cut The Rope" (only a similar graphic, not the complexity of the game)).

**Question 3:** Is it possible to do this without using game engines?

**Question 4:** Searching on Google I read that it's possible to develop apps in flash+AS3+Java and export them in .apk files, is it true? will there be any problems with the graphic components when executing in Android?

**Question 5:** Using this development system (if possible), what about iOS compatibility?

PS: I know how to develop simple apps using Eclipse but I started learning Java only some weeks ago, my problem is that my apps are too much "droid" looking.

Comment: Stop apologizing for your English, its fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, though you don't run the games on Flash Player, you run them as an [AIR Application exported for Android](http://www.adobe.com/inspire-archive/august2010/articles/article1/index.html?trackingid=HRTDI).
2. No.
3. Of course. With that said, I strongly recommend the use of [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/), especially in this context. It has the same learning curve as the traditional display and event APIs, but offers far better performance (through GPU rendering capabilities) and comes with components tailored specifically for mobile development.
4. Yes, see the link in point 1.
5. Exact same process for iOS, just select AIR for iOS rather than AIR for Android.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! Fortunately ActionScript seems to be syntactically similar to Java, even if I must start studying it from zero. So after some months (i hope) will I be able to create something graphically similar to "Cut The Rope" or "Angry Birds" using flash+ActionScript and play them on my Android/iOS device?

Comment: @user2812033 I don't think it will take you anything more than about a week to get running with AS3+Starling if you have existing programming knowledge, especially if that were an OOP language like Java. I am curious though - why learn AS3 for mobile development if you already know Java?

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, I'm able to create something like Quizzes. I only know basilar notions of Java programming, as I started studying it a month ago, just for hobby. What I would like to learn is how to create an app with a fully customized graphic UI (like games i mentioned), and I'm trying to understand which language can let me do this the easiest way. If I will fail with Flash + AS3 I'll continue learning the Java's (Impossible) graphic development. Otherwise I don't have any basic knowledge of graphic programming so,for now, can't use JMonkey or Unity.

Comment: @user2812033 Thing with Flash is that though it's easy, it's falling behind very rapidly and it's not a skill that I see being used in the future. Unity is definitely the way to go if you were willing to put a little more effort into your learning. I myself am in the process of learning Unity, after several years of Flash game development.

Comment: I know Flash won't be used anymore but, starting from zero, I think I need to begin with something "simple" and then, in less than a year, start using game engines like JM or Unity. My problem is that I started using PC's when I was 6, but never tryied to program, and now some aspects of high-level languages seems to be too difficult and impossible to learn. I'm just a bit confused even because I can't find online guides or tutorials that let you learn starting from zero. Everyone explains you what to do but not how to do. Most of my working apps is due to Stackoverflow community.